# Snapsvg animate gradient moving

Tags: javascript, animation, snap.svg

I have an arrow with gradient:

```
var g = field.gradient("l(0, 1, 2, 1)#fff-#5C5C5C");
var arrow = field.path(Snap.format("M390 385 L335 335 L410 355 Q375 355 390 385")).attr({fill: g, opacity: 0.5, cursor: 'pointer'});
```

I want to make an effect that the gradient is changing/moving like waves or something..

Here's flash page with what I want: http://www.888poker.com/poker-client/euromania_popup.htm?isftd=1&origcid=123456

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try animating the gradient, something like..

```
s = Snap(400, 620);

var g = s.gradient("l(0, 1, 2, 1)#5C5C5C-#fff-#5C5C5C");
var arrow = s.path(Snap.format("M390 385 L335 335 L410 355 Q375 355 390 385")).attr({fill: g, opacity: 0.5, cursor: 'pointer'});

function anim () {
    g.attr({ x1: 0, y1: 1, x2: 2, y2: 1 });
    g.animate({ x1: 0, y1: 100, x2: 0, y2: 100 }, 2000, mina.linear, anim);
};

anim();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Cs8F/2/)

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a way to animate the colors of the gradient? I've tried looking into the source code for the gradient and it looks like the colors are called "stops" but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use them in the animate function.

Comment: I don't know a way to specifically animate the colors. You can change the stop colors like http://jsfiddle.net/2Cs8F/5/ but I don't know a way to gradually change the colors as part of an animation if thats what you are after. You may be able to get what you need from that and combining the right colors in the gradient though.

Comment: Thank you, that is further than I got. I will mess with it some more. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ian's link was on the right track. You can access an array of the color stop positions as percentages along the gradient and animate them individually with code like this:

```
// 1st color stop moves to 25% from the end over 1000ms
g.selectAll("*")[0].animate({offset: 0.25}, 1000)
// 2nd color stop moves to the 50% point over 500ms
g.selectAll("*")[0].animate({offset: 0.50}, 500)
// 3rd color stop moves to 75% from the end over 300ms
g.selectAll("*")[0].animate({offset: 0.75}, 300)
```